# Is the limit of the function is $0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

According to wolfram alpha,$$\lim _{x \to \ 0} \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} \cdot \sin\left(\frac 1 x\right)=0$$

**In my question, the function is defined only in $(0,\infty)$**
I want to prove it through the squeeze theorem.

I think that:

$$-x\le\frac{\cos x}{\sin x} \cdot \sin\left(\frac 1 x \right)\le x$$

And because $\lim_{x\to 0}-x=0,\lim_{x\to 0}-x=0$, according to the squeeze theorem, the limit equals $0$.

Is it correct?

P.S - the original question was about $\arctan x \cdot\sin\left(\frac 1 x \right) $ however through some calculations I wrote it as above.

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: What you have is cotangent, which is very different from arctangent...

Comment: Isn't $arctanx=(tanx)^{-1}=(\frac{sinx}{cosx})^{-1}=\frac{cosx}{sinx}$?

Comment: No, $arctanx$ is not $(tanx)^{-1}$, it is the inverse function of the tan(x). Please check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions

Comment: $\arctan x$ is sometimes written as $\tan^{-1} x$, but that does not mean the same thing as $(\tan x)^{-1}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to find $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0} \left(\arctan x\cdot\sin \left( \frac 1 x\right)\right)$ is first to notice that $|\sin(\text{anything})|\le 1$ so that
$$
-|\arctan x|\le \arctan x\cdot\sin\left(\frac 1 x \right) \le |\arctan x|
$$
and then find $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\arctan x$.

Comment: Thank you. It's so easy I feel like an idiot.

Answer (score 1):

$$ - \tan^{-1}(x) \le  \tan^{-1}(x) \sin (\frac 1x ) \le \tan^{-1}(x) $$

and $$\lim _{x \to 0} \tan^{-1}(x) = 0 $$

Comment: This is valid when $\tan^{-1} x>0$. A teensy bit of additional work will take care of the case where $\tan^{-1}x<0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: really the limit is $\lim _{x \to 0^+}$